# Moving objects in the most current swift

Tags: xcode, swift

How would I go about moving an object to follow touch in the newest version of swift. So if you touch the object it will follow your finger around until you remove your finger.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` methods.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        thing.center = (touch.locationInView(self.view))

    }

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        thing.center = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    }
}
```

For more info, watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D2KNOFtowQ). Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be more helpful now.